# How to display the hex value in the Watch panel of VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I started to use VS Code on Linux and I'd like to see the hex value of a variable near its value. I need it because the variable is a mask, so it is composed of 0's and 1's on certain positions. I did not manage to find a setting or something like it to add it.

Is it possible? I am using C++ code. I see that the addresses are in hex, so is there a way to see the value of a variable in hex, too?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In the watch window, type `<variable-name>,h`.

Comment: In general, you should look for: https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_54.html

Thus <variable-name>,t should work but does not for me at least.
Please ask on VSCode GitHub forum, perhaps they do not pass this properly to underlying GDB.

Of course, you can always switch to debug console in the bottom and type where: -exec p/t <variable-name>.

Comment: Are all format token from Visual Studio compatible with Visual Code (like `<data>,su` ) ?

Comment: Didn't work for me, "Error: Unrecognized format of field"

Comment: It works for C/C++ programs on Win/Linux with GNU. For Python, one should use hex(<variable>) instead. So it's not universal solution as Visual Code calls debugging backend for it , as far as I remember. Check lldb's CLI syntax to print value in hex and try it instead of 'h' (in GDB, print /h <variable>)

Answer (score 2):

Adding ,h etc didn't work for me (at least on lldb on mac).

Try casting the variable to the output type you want:

Example for hex:

```
(void*)test3x1[1]
```

Example for integer:

```
(int)test3x1[1]
```

Comment: this would not provide hex representation.

Comment: Added a hex example

Comment: Worked for me on `arm-none-eabi-gdb`. But it depends on gdb version

Answer (score 1):

In the Watch window of VS Code, you can enter the following:

```
hex(variable name)
```

Comment: A screenshot would have been helpful, because it works: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h7D0.png

Comment: Note that only works if there is an "hex" immutable, global function that encodes the value as string. E.g. in python