# How to set the format of watched variables as hexdecimal in VS Code with GDB?

Tags: visual-studio-code, hex, watch, vscode-debugger

GDB: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
VS Code: 1.52.1(system setup)

I just want to get the hexadecimal value of some variable while debugging.

I tried to add the variable like "`variable,h`" and "`variable,x`" but it shows the error

> Must specify the format as: 'natural', 'binary', 'decimal', 'hexadecimal', or 'octal'

Is there any proper solution to this situation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display the hex value in the Watch panel of VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39973214/how-to-display-the-hex-value-in-the-watch-panel-of-vs-code)

Answer (score 2):

Format specifiers `<variable>,h` and `<variable>,x` are mapped in GDB to the zero-hexadecimal output format (*/z*). It is like */x* formatting, the value is treated as an integer and printed as hexadecimal, but leading zeros are printed to pad the value to the size of the integer type. A newer GDB version (>=7.11) is required to support it. For more information, you can read [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/557) on the repository of the C/C++ extension for VS Code.

If you want to get the hexadecimal value, a workaround would be to watch the variable as a void pointer: `(void *)variable`